# Elasticsearch: Filter documents with empty geo_point value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query an elasticsearch index for documents with an empty geo_point field. The field exists but it's blank (example below). A query which works for filtering `string` fields does not work for `geo_point` fields.

Document:

```
"_source": {
"latitudeLongitude": "",
"pickupLocationZipcode": "",
}
```

Query that works for filtering string fields but not geo_point fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "latitudeLongitude": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping:

```
"latitudeLongitude": {
  "type": "geo_point"
}
"pickupLocationZipcode": {
  "index": "not_analyzed",
    "type": "string",
    "copy_to": [
      "pickup_location_zipcode"
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`missing` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-query.html) for this and it will find your document

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "latitudeLongitude",
          "existence": false,
          "null_value": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```